# Getting a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session Keycloak

Tags: hibernate, keycloak, keycloak-services

We are trying to authenticate an existing user via Keycloak so implemented a custom SPI and added the custom SPI as User Federation

Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.keycloak.storage.jpa.entity.FederatedUserRoleMappingEntity#org.keycloak.storage.jpa.entity.FederatedUserRoleMappingEntity$Key@e3a03493]

We are trying to use Keycloak for authentication and using the custom provider to authenticate the users the user details are are in custom provider using Storage  provider SPI

```
@Override
public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
    UserModel userModel = new UserAdapter(session, realm, model, repository.findUserByUsernameOrEmail(username));
    RoleModel roleModel = realm.getRole("user");
    userModel.grantRole(roleModel);
    return userModel;

}
```

The exception is happening when adding the "user" role and the realm this user is trying to add has role 'user' when i don't add the user role web application is redirected to keycloak web page for adding the user .... 
[image: Realm containing the user role]

Newbie to keycloak any help wll be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So I just solved this myself in our custom SPI.  The reason this happens is because there is already a user in the cache/database with this role assigned.  When you log in using the form at Keycloak, it makes several calls down into the interfaces your SPI implements in order to look up the user and cache/store it somewhere.

In order to fix this you could do something like the following:

```
@Override
public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
    UserModel userModel = new UserAdapter(session, realm, model, 
    repository.findUserByUsernameOrEmail(username));
    RoleModel roleModel = realm.getRole("user");

    //Change is here
    //---------------------------------------------------
    if (!userModel.getRoleMappings().contains(roleModel))
        userModel.grantRole(roleModel);
    //---------------------------------------------------        

    return userModel;
}
```

Once you call the `grantRole` method, if the role is currently granted to the persisted user then the `EntityExistsException` gets thrown.  This should solve your issue.